SQLI Blind Injection Conditional Errors Issue
I am taking the course in Portswigger.net for SQLi and am stuck in Lab 12 where I cant seem to get the administrator password. I am using this https://github.com/rkhal101/Web-Security-Academy-Series/blob/main/sql-injection/lab-12/sqli-lab-12.py python script to get the password since I am only using burp community edition and I keep getting proxy errors. Here is the error am getting:
python3  sqli-lab-12.py "https://0aaf00f503f92c0181a707140080003c.web-security-academy.net/"
(+) Retreiving administrator password...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 777, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1046, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 611, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd62b7fead0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

urllib3.exceptions.ProxyError: ('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd62b7fead0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 667, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 845, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0aaf00f503f92c0181a707140080003c.web-security-academy.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd62b7fead0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acid/Downloads/sqli-lab-12.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/acid/Downloads/sqli-lab-12.py", line 36, in main
    sqli_password(url)
  File "/home/acid/Downloads/sqli-lab-12.py", line 18, in sqli_password
    r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, verify=False, proxies=proxies)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 694, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0aaf00f503f92c0181a707140080003c.web-security-academy.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd62b7fead0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))`

I am wondering where the problem might be so anyone can help me.
I have tried to change the proxy by using http instead of https and vice-versa but still getting the error

Whatever address you're trying to connect to isn't running an HTTP server.
